# Excel send email via gmail over proxy server

Tags: excel, vba, proxy, gmail

any expert can point out my mistake ? Sincerely thank for your suggestion and solution.

Below is my code, i always receive complaint (run time error). So wish any expert can point out my mistake. thanks..

```
Dim NewMail As CDO.Message
Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP
Set myMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set NewMail = New CDO.Message

    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxyserver") = "proxy.server:8080"
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxybypass") = "<local>"
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "user@gmail.com"
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

    With NewMail
        .Subject = "my subject here"
        .From = "user@gmail.com"
        .To = "receiver@gmail.com"
        .CC = "" 
        .TextBody = "my text body here"
        .AddAttachment "myattach.pdf"
        NewMail.Send
    End With
```

Comment: The error is telling you. Why keep it secret. The To line is missing a quote.

Comment: Dear expert, thanks. I miss the double quote.

Answer (score 0):

`NewMail.Send` should be just `.Send`.

Alternatively, try this reduction of your code:

```
Dim NewMail As Object 
Set NewMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
With NewMail 
   .Subject = "my subject here"
   .From = "user@gmail.com"
   .To = "receiver@gmail.com"
   .CC = "" 
   .BCC = "" 
   .TextBody = "my text body here"
   .AddAttachment "myattach.pdf"
   .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxyserver") = "proxy.server:8080"
    Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxybypass") = "<local>"
   .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True 
   .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 
   .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "user@gmail.com" 
   .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password" 
   .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com" 
   .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
   .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465 
   .Update 
End With 
NewMail.Send
```

I have no idea if your proxy is configured correctly, but make sure you check your port number.

Comment: Hi expert, How about the proxy ? anything wrong ? The error also said " transport failed to connect to the server" is it all related to .Send ?  Sincerely thanks for your help.

Comment: Try removing the proxy lines.